# Python 3, networking. Keep server open and make multiple connections?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a simple server/client with the use of a class, which should lead to a method inside the class test which can make connections to the server on demand, and not just once. ultimately I'm trying for this class test to run the method main twice, one for "hello" and "world" which should print in the console:

HELLO
WORLD

client:

```
import socket

class test(object):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def main(self, send):
        host = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 5009

        s = socket.socket()
        s.connect((host, port))

        message = send
        message = bytes(message, "utf-8")
        while message != "q":
            s.send(message)
            data = s.recv(1024)
            data = str(data, "utf-8")
            print("Received from server: " + str(data))
        s.close()

d = test("Run")
d.main("hello")
d.main("world")
```

How can I make my server be up at all times aswell? And not close the socket after having been run once?

server:

```
import socket

def main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5009

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print("Connect" + str(addr))
    while True:
        data = c.recv(1024)
        data = str(data, "utf-8")
        print(data)
        if not data:
            break
        data = bytes(data.upper(), "utf-8")
        c.send(data)
    c.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well, your server is closing the connection, isn't it? Start by not closing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeat the accept part like so:

```
import socket

def main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 5009

    s = socket.socket()
    s.bind((host, port))

    s.listen(1)
    while True:
        c, addr = s.accept()
        print("Connect" + str(addr))
        while True:
            data = c.recv(1024)
            data = str(data, "utf-8")
            print(data)
            if not data:
                break
            data = bytes(data.upper(), "utf-8")
            c.send(data)
        c.close()
    s.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Well, you set `message` to "hello" and then you test if `message` != 'q'. That's probably not what you want. Since the message does not change in the while loop that condition will never be true. Instead maybe remove the client while loop, or add some termination condition